# How to display errors to the users in a proper way?

Tags: php, user-interface, error-handling

I'm building a big Web application and I need a decent system to display errors to the users (using PHP and non-obtrusive JavaScript). So far, when an error is detected, the application redirects to an `error.php` page and, depending on the link, it displays a message.

For example, if the user submits a form in `accountCreation.php` blank, then it redirects to `www.example.com/error/FIELD_IS_EMPTY`, and then `error.php` retrieves the message to display and prints it, like this:

```
switch ($_GET['message']) {
case 'FIELD_IS_EMPTY':
    echo "You can't leave the field blank.";
    break;

case 'TOO_LONG':
    echo "Text must be shorter than 128 characters.";
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

At least it works, but I don't know if this is a scalable way to do it. Also, if someone enters to `www.example.com/error/FIELD_IS_EMPTY`, it will display the error, even though the user never even submitted the form. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438022/php-redirection-not-working

Comment: strictly speaking it's not errors but rather regular messages. So, I see no point in redirecting user anywhere.

Comment: I posted a link with my answer to the similar question. Quite trivial one, though

Comment: Are you sure it's best to NOT redirect? It's more user-friendly, that I agree with, but if you have a lot of possible errors,it might get a bit messy

Comment: what? what's messy here?

Answer (score -1):

Best way to handle errors is

1. 404, 505, 303 related errors, you can redirect to a standard error page. Which is dynamically handle the error message based on the error status
2. Errors related to field information, wrong entries and soon. Handle those on the same page itself and show it there.

Comment: Why redirect? what's the point in sending 301 and 503 in turn?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: For displaying custom error message, its the best way to do. Rather than default messages.

Comment: if you are able to send an HTTP header, you are able to send a custom error page as well. So, the question again - why redirect?

Answer (score -1):

Have you think to block the direct access to this page with a simple method like: if the user complete the form you create a constant (like `$_SESSION['formComplete'] = true;` ) and in the  page where you want to control the error put a script for check if the constant is set otherwise redirect to the another page. Here there is a sample:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['formComplete'])) {
    header("location:index.php"); 
    die();
}
```