# Organizing a PHP page with a bunch of $_POST's

Tags: php, code-organization

I am making quite a large online points/purchasing system in PHP and just have a fundamental question.

All the relevant stuff is on a single PHP page within the site, with "includes" from other parts of the site such as shopping cart, points review, products etc..., but throughout the page there are stages where the user clicks a form submit button to pass values via $_POST.

As there is a main page for all this stuff, I have a part at the top of the page where it takes all the POST values and makes decisions based upon them, like so:

```
if($_POST['add']) {
    $product_id = $_POST['add'];
}

if($_POST['remove']) {
       $rid = $_POST['id'];
       $cart->del_item($rid);                   
}
if($_POST['empty']){    
   $cart->empty_cart();
} 
if($_POST['purchase']) {
   foreach($cart->get_contents() as $item) {
     $sql="INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty_orders VALUES (".$user_id.", ".$item['id'].")";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
   }

   $cart->empty_cart();
   unset($_SESSION['cart']);            
}       
if($_POST['add']) {
   query_posts('post_type=prizes&showposts=-1&p='.$product_id.''); 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
   $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);


   if($calctotalnew > $my_meta['pointsvalue']){
      $cart->add_item(get_the_id(), 1, $my_meta['pointsvalue'], get_the_title());
   } else {
      echo 'You do not have sufficient points to redeem this product...';
   }

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();  
}
```

So my question is... is this really a good way to organize a system, having the form actions go to the same page that the form is on, and have a load of IF statements to decide what to do with the POST values?

Thanks! :)

Comment: you have 2 `if($_POST['add'])` statements

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel which is perfectly fine in theory :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's generally best to capture separate POST calls (grouped by type) in separate actions. I usually go as follows:

page 1 has a form, which will submit to eg. product.php?action=add. In product.php you can route the 'add' action to the function add_product() (or whatever). Then when the product is added, just header the user back to the main page (or whatever page you'd like). This immediately tackles the problem with refresh-posts (user refreshing the page which will send the same data again).

following mvc imagine you have a controller `Product` which handles all the product actions. The skeleton could look like this (assuming function action_x will be executed when `yoursite.com/product/x` is requested):

```
class Product_Controller {
    function action_show() {
    }

    function action_update() {
    }

    function action_delete() {
    }
}
```

if your framework supports a default action of some sort you could route your actions:

```
function action_default() {
    if(method_exists(array($this, 'action_'. $_POST['action']))) {
        return call_user_method('action_'. $_POST['action'], $this);
    }
}
```

ofcourse the same can be achieved without controller classes;

```
if(function_exists('action_'. $_POST['action'])) {
    call_user_func('action_'. $_POST['action']);
}

function action_show() { }
...
```

and to illustrate the discussion in the comments;

```
function action_update() {
    // do some update logic, query an UPDATE to mysql etc.
    if($result) {
        // optionally save a success message
        Message::add('Your record has been updated');
        header('Location: main_page.php'); // or another intelligent redirect function
    } else {
        Message::add('Sorry, something went wrong');
        header('Location: error_page.php'); // or also main_page
    }
}
```

This will also keep your code cleaner, as updating/adding/deleting stuff is radically different from showing stuff, this will prevent you from mixing up stuff. You could even call the show function from within the update function if you want to skip the redirect.

But in the end it's a matter of choice, led by pragmatism or your framework ;)

I hope this'll explain everything a bit, don't hesitate to ask for clarification

Comment: what a boring design. a dozen of files, 1-2 line in each?

Comment: i think you've missed the point... at least it would be decent btw to explain yourself instead of just hitting out, don't you think? have you never tried some hmvc? than this would sound familiar to you. but i agree, it can sometimes be boring to be a programmer, but hey, boring isn't necessarily bad is it?

Comment: Ahh ok I see. I think I used that way before, but when you post to a new page, this page is not styled or anything? Or is it the case that the header will automatically direct the user back to the current page?

Comment: i think you missed the point on the question then. the question was about product.php file, not other files

Comment: yup, basically the "processing"-page doesn't send any output (except for the headers). It just processes the data and immediately redirects the user to the designated page (your main page or whatever). Normally a user wouldn't notice the page refreshes twice. It also gives you an easy way of showing errors (loading a template file or redirect to an error page instead).

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel does that prevents one to suggest an alternative?

Comment: Ok yeah I have deffo used that before, I just had a problem with it because... say you wanted to show an error in a specific place in the page, depening on an if statement... how would you decide which error to show on the visual client page?

Comment: Well, you both confusing php scripts with displayed pages. There is absolute no reason in having separate php script to handle POST exclusively. Quite contrary, proper design would be to keep all page routines in one script.

Comment: @JamesG i normally let the "processor" set an errormessage (if of any use with an error number) in a "flash"-session var (a session variable which only survives one request). Then on the other page (which can be a normal page with an error-div or a default error page), just check if there are any errors and if so, show it.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel yeah that's what i meant when i said you missed the point. Let's say you have some 'product' controllers, ie. grouped in a class `class Product_Controller { }` with, among them, some action-functions, like `function action_add() { }`, `function action_show() { }` and `function action_update() { }`. This separates every bit of logic in a normal mvc way, but i don't see any extra files, or files with 1-2 lines. So please try to explain what you are talking about. I really don't understand why you are so grumpy...

Comment: yeah, may be I was too fast to judge. if you edit your answer, I will be able to take my downvote back

Comment: i hope i made myself a bit clearer with my edit, thanks for the feedback anyway

Answer (score 2):

if you want to separate the logic from the interface then you can simple create new file and put the all logical and database related code in that file and include OR require that file in the view file

like
view.php interface file and
logic.php is your logic file then

first line in view.php is
require_once(logic.php');

and all the logic is in this files

simple MVC

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems I have to explain.

1. It absolutely does not matter how much IF statements you have in the POST handler. Your current design is okay, and there is no reason to ask nor change it.
2. The only thing that you may wish to add to your design is a *front controller*, which will take both entity (cart)  and action("add") and call add() method of $cart class. these methods you may store one under another in the class source.
   Though it is quite huge improvement, requiring great rethinking of the whole site architecture. So, you may stick with your current one.
3. As for your **other** question, how to display errors, here is an answer: [php redirection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438022/php-redirection-not-working)

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for that, really cleared a few things up! I have been using jQuery's ajax functionallity $.ajax{} which seems to be good at this sort of thing, as you can instantly get replies from a processing page and have the success handler print the error message wherever you want. I just wanted to know a non ajax way of doing it and this is brilliant. Especially the error handling :) thanks

Comment: I have adapted my design so there is the error handling as you suggested, but I am encountering a "Headers already sent" error. I have had these errors before but really confusing because a lot of people say its whitespace at start and end of PHP file but its deffinately not this. Here is my code at the top of my file:
'code' 
<?php
/* Template Name: Account Page */
require_once('profile/account-logic.php');
get_header();
wp_get_current_user();
?>

Comment: But in the require_once('profile/account-logic.php'); I have the line header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); as you suggested. Is the problem something to do with this?